# how pass and change url with query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

so I do a little project with react and node js
and i do a search function that work fine but I just have a little problem i try to figure

I do a function that I search for items with a search word that I send in query and categories to filter in req.body
so I send a post request to my back-end and I want to change the url client by the values I post to the server

for example lets say my url is localhost:3001/home
and i send to the server the serach word "football" and in categories I send sport

so i want my url look like this localhost:3001/home?search=football&cate=sport

i add here my code from the front

look on the function "searchFun"

```js
React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import BookItem from "../bookItem/bookItem";
import './Home.css'
import Logo from "../logo/logo";
import Checkbox from "../CheckBox/CheckBox";

function HomePage() {
    const [comedyBooks, setComedy] = useState([])
    const [sportBooks, setSport] = useState([])
    const [actionBooks, setAction] = useState([])
    const [displaySearch, setDisplaySearch] = useState([])
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    const [boxFilter, setBoxFilter] = useState({
        comedy: false,
        action: false,
        sport: false,
    })

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        let booksArr = []
        let comedyBook = []
        let sportBook = []
        let actionBook = []

        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/books')
            .then(async res => {
                res.data.data.books.map(el => {
                    booksArr.push(el)
                })
                comedyBook = booksArr.filter(el => el.categories == 'comedy')
                sportBook = booksArr.filter(el => el.categories == 'sport')
                actionBook = booksArr.filter(el => el.categories == 'action')
                setAction(actionBook)
                setSport(sportBook)
                setComedy(comedyBook)

            })
    }, [])

    const searchFun = () => {
        try {
            axios.create({ withCredentials: true }).post(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/books/search?search=${search}`, {
                categories: boxFilter
            })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data.data1)
                    setDisplaySearch(res.data.data1)
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log((error))
        }
    }

    const handleChangeAction = () => {
        setBoxFilter({ ...boxFilter, action: !boxFilter.action })
    }
    const handleChangeSport = () => {
        setBoxFilter({ ...boxFilter, sport: !boxFilter.sport })
    }
    const handleChangeComedy = () => {
        setBoxFilter({ ...boxFilter, comedy: !boxFilter.comedy })
    }


   

    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <Logo />
                <img className="sub-logo" src='https://www.booknet.co.il/images/site/pages/d_1799_auto_49e74940-d1a2-4fe1-9645-6b526eb69600.jpg' />
            </header>
            <div>
                <input onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} placeholder="Search..." />
                <button onClick={searchFun}>Search</button>
                <Checkbox label='action' value={boxFilter.action} onChange={handleChangeAction} />
                <Checkbox label='sport' value={boxFilter.sport} onChange={handleChangeSport} />
                <Checkbox label='comedy' value={boxFilter.comedy} onChange={handleChangeComedy} />
            </div>
            {/* <div className="displaySearch"> */}
            {displaySearch.length >= 1 ? displaySearch.map(item => {
                return <BookItem key={item._id} item={item} />
            }) : null}
            {/* </div> */}
            <div className="sub-logo-container">
            </div>
            <div className="home-container">
                <p className="title-cat">Comedy Books</p>
                <div className="line-bottom"></div>
                <div className="books">
                    {comedyBooks.map(item => {
                        return <BookItem key={item._id} item={item} />
                    })}
                </div>

                <p className="title-cat">Sport Books</p>
                <div className="line-bottom"></div>
                <div className="books">
                    {sportBooks.map(item => {
                        return <BookItem key={item._id} item={item} />
                    })}
                </div>

                <p className="title-cat">Action Books</p>
                <div className="line-bottom"></div>
                <div className="books">
                    {actionBooks.map(item => {
                        return <BookItem key={item._id} item={item} />
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

my App component

```js
import React, {  useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './app.css'
import Account from "./Components/account/account";
import AddBook from "./Components/AddBook/AddBook";
import ForgetPassword from "./Components/auth/forgetpassword/forgetpassword";
import Login from "./Components/auth/login/Login";
import ResetPassword from "./Components/auth/resetPassword/resetPassword";
import SignIn from "./Components/auth/sign-in/Sign-in";
import DisplayBook from "./Components/displayBook/displayBook";
import DisplayCart from "./Components/displayCart/displayCart";
import Home from './Components/Home/Home'
import Logo from "./Components/logo/logo";
import MyBooks from "./Components/mybooks/mybooks";
import NavBar from './Components/navBar/navBar'


function App() {
  const [cookie, setCookie] = useState()
  const name = "elyasaf"

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <NavBar set={setCookie} />
      {/* <Logo /> */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login set={setCookie} />} />
        <Route path="/myAccount" element={<Account />} />
        <Route path="/logo" element={<Logo />} />
        <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/forgetpassword" element={<ForgetPassword />} />
        <Route path="/users/resetPassword/:token" element={<ResetPassword />} />
        <Route path="/addBook" element={<AddBook />} />
        <Route path="/MyBooks" element={<MyBooks />} />
        <Route path="/MyCart" element={<DisplayCart />} />
        <Route path="/book/:bookId" element={<DisplayBook />} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using a router at all?

Comment: yes i do all the route in the App component

Comment: but i stay still in the same page when i using the search function